# Selectize.js - not showing options

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I have an array that I send from the backend, from which I create a new array of objects, for which I then use JSON.stringify to make it ready for the `selectize`, the array looks like this then:

```
[{"question":"Challenge question"},{"question":"Challenge question"},{"question":"Challenge question"}... and so on
```

I am trying to use that new array with selectize, but no option gets rendered:

This is the script:

```
var engagementsOptions = [];
icoop.engagements.map(function(item) {
   engagementsOptions.push({
        "question" : item
    });
});

$('#engagement_question').selectize({
    options: JSON.stringify(engagementsOptions),
    create: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the string you are constructing for the options argument. I think it should be a comma-delimited string.  Try something like this maybe (not tested with selectize, just based on the docs)?

```
//example data
var data_from_server = [{"question":"Challenge question 1"},{"question":"Challenge question 2"},{"question":"Challenge question 3"}];

var engagementsOptions = [];
data_from_server.map(function(item) { engagementsOptions.push(item["question"]); });

$('#engagement_question').selectize({
    options: engagementsOptions.join(','),
    create: true,
});
```